# How to get the key value in key-value array

Tags: typescript, angular6

I have the following expression:

```
export const alpha: [
    { 'A': ['11','12','13'] },
    { 'B': ['21','22','23'] },
    { 'C': ['31','32','33'] }
];
```

I need to create a new array that has the leading keys: 'A', 'B' and 'C'

I'm trying to do this, but there is no `key` property:

```
const arr = [];
alpha.forEach(function(item) {
  arr.push(item.key);
});
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```js
const alpha = [
    { 'A': ['11','12','13'] },
    { 'B': ['21','22','23'] },
    { 'C': ['31','32','33'] }
];

const arr = [];

alpha.forEach(function(item) {
  arr.push(Object.keys(item)[0]);
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would build it up deconstructing the array like so:

```
let newArray6 = {'A':[ ...alpha[0].A],'B':[ ...alpha[1].B],'C':[ ...alpha[2].C]}
```

This could then be easily turned into a programmatic loop :)

The output would be as follows:

```
A: (3) ["11", "12", "13"]
B: (3) ["21", "22", "23"]
C: (3) ["31", "32", "33"]
```